# Jquery: Trying to disable HTML select menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-selectmenu

On my HTML page I have a few select menus which all share the class name `.iconDropDownMenu` and when the page is generated with PHP some of the select menus will have been hidden by PHP adding another class to the select menu.

Anyway I then wanted to disable only the hidden `.iconDropDownMenu` which I have been trying to use the following:

```
$(".iconDropDownMenu:hidden").each(function()
{
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

This runs without no errors but the disabled attribute does not show up on my select menu, thus not disabling input. So I did some research and found that I could use `$(this).multiselect('refresh');` inside my .each() above after the first line. However I get an error **TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function** and this is the weird part it actually works, I can see the disabled attribute in the HTML but the error stops the rest of the JavaScript to run...

I also tried using `$(this).selectmenu("refresh");` but get the following: Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' and this also produces the same result, being the disabled attribute to the select menu is added whereas without this it did not before.

I tried to initialize the select menu but it just adds a span to the HTML and messes up select menu by showing the first selection as text outside the select menu?

I also tried to use PHP to output the "disabled" attribute to the select menu HTML but when loaded in the browser it does not show and is removed :/

Comment: Please, what so you mean by *will have been hidden by PHP* ?  *but the disabled attribute does not show up on my select menu* ?

Comment: Try to use `attr()` instead of `prop`.

Comment: please share HTML code as well to debug easily

Comment: I mean that I have basically used PHP to echo out "disabled" in the select HTML <select... disabled></select> but in the browser it does not show up, but if I were to echo out "disabledA" it would show. You know when you press F12 to view code.

Comment: Sounds like your JS may need to go into a `$(document).ready();`, here is an example ... https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/vkuhm93s/. Without a little more detail though, it's hard to give a more specific answer.

Comment: i have created example -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xOJjyE

Comment: what is  the error  in your console?

Comment: OMG! Totally my fault. I feel so silly now. Because I was using a external .JS file which is quite big, I forgot it never had a `$(document).ready();` function :( Thank you so much though. It works now!

Comment: I moved my comment out as an answer for posterity's sake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your JS may need to go into a `$(document).ready();`, here is an example ... https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/vkuhm93s/.